# How to detect connection loss with couchbase server

Tags: java, couchbase

Is there a way to detect a connection loss with the couchbase cluster using the java client.
I have tried using **addObserver()** and adding my listeners, but it never reports a connection loss.

Comment: I'm wondering what the use case here is. Why do you need to know this? The couchbase client should take care of all the details of reconnecting to the cluster/server.

Comment: The couchbase client takes some time(2.5 secs is the default timeout) to detect that the connection has been lost.

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this? And how did you know that 2,5sec is the default timeout (can't find it in the docs)?